# XNA SpriteBatch instantiation issue

Tags: xna

I've been practicing certain techniques in XNA and lately came across an issue that's just confusing me. I've been using this technique for a few of my Windows Game Projects and all of a sudden now theres a problem, I think i'm overlooking something...

So I created a fresh Windows Game Project and added a XNA Game Componant to the project, added the componant to the Game1.cs file. Created and instantiated a SpriteBatch variable in the Componant then tried to draw a simple texture to test the spriteBatch.

Here's a picture of the runtime error I get: http://twitpic.com/3jp8t1 
...and the full source of the two files: pastebin.com/rFRkGKXJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head (you can double-check me using Reflector), the order of calls during XNA initialisation is this:

- `Initialize()` in your game class
- `LoadContent()` in your game *components* (called from `Game.Initialize`)
- `LoadContent()` in your game class (called from `Game.Initialize`)
- Update and draw calls

(This is not the full list, by the way.)

So I would guess that, by adding the game component in your game's `LoadContent` function, the `LoadContent` in your game component is not being called so its `SpriteBatch` is not being created. You could check this by adding a breakpoint in your game component's `LoadContent` function.

Generally you want to create and add your game components in your game's `Initialize` function.

(Also you should, and possibly need to, call the respective `base` functions in `LoadContent` and `UnloadContent`.)

Personally I prefer to avoid using `DrawableGameComponent` and just make my own free-standing class. This lets me share instances of `SpriteBatch` more directly (rather than having to create ones for each component) and it lets me more explicitly control the order things are called in.

Comment: I faced this issue quite often until I figured out the order in which all the ctor-ish  functions are called. IF the issue persists, call, Initialize() and then LoadContent() in your constructor as a patch, and it should be fixed!